# Is there a keyboard binding for seeing ping rate?

Tags: supreme-commander-2

In Supreme Commander 2, is there a way to display the ping rate you can see in the multi-player lobby while you are actually playing the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During a Multiplayer game, you can hit F2 to show Rankings / Ping of current players within the game.